# InfoPath adding a new row programmatically to end of list

Tags: c#, xpath, infopath

I am currently helping a client creating a form with InfoPath and Im having some problems getting my lists to act like I want.

Whenever I add a new element to a list (Repeating Section) it ends up on top of the list in the view, and I want it to be added to the bottom. My client wants a custom button to trigger the addition of the element and not use the "add element" text that InfoPath provides.

Here is an example to better explain my problem:

[image]

When a user writes in a something in the input field, I want it to be added to the list in the repeating section. Here is a sample code:

```
private XPathNavigator GetField(string xPath)
{
    return MainDataSource.CreateNavigator()
                         .SelectSingleNode(xPath, NamespaceManager);
}

public void CTRL10_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string xPathToList = "/my:myFields/my:group5/my:group6/my:group7";
    string xPathToInput = "/my:myFields/my:group5/my:field2";
    string xPathToListElement = xPathToList + "/my:field3";

    //Creates a new row
    XPathNavigator list = GetField(xPathToList);
    XPathNavigator newRow = list.Clone();
    newRow.InsertAfter(list);

    //Sets values on the new row
    XPathNavigator input = GetField(xPathToInput);
    XPathNavigator nameField = GetField(xPathToListElement);
    nameField.SetValue(input.Value);
    input.SetValue("");
}
```

When I add a new element to the list it is added to the top of the list, not the bottom..
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I made it work with was getting the last ( [last()] ) element in the list in the XPath expression, and adding the element to after the specified element.

```
private XPathNavigator GetField(string xPath)
{
     return MainDataSource.CreateNavigator()
                          .SelectSingleNode(xPath, NamespaceManager);
}

public void CTRL10_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string xPathToList = "/my:myFields/my:group5/my:group6/my:group7[last()]";
    string xPathToInput = "/my:myFields/my:group5/my:field2";
    string xPathToListElement = xPathToList + "/my:field3";

    //Creates a new row
    XPathNavigator list = GetField(xPathToList);
    XPathNavigator newRow = list.Clone();
    newRow.InsertAfter(list);

    //Sets values on the new row
    XPathNavigator input = GetField(xPathToInput);
    XPathNavigator nameField = GetField(xPathToListElement);
    nameField.SetValue(input.Value);
    input.SetValue("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

`CurrentView.ExecuteAction(ActionType.XCollectionInsert, "XmlToEdit");`

which should do the same job as the inbuilt infopath "add element".  Just replace the "XmlToEdit" with the name of your group you want to insert into.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With InfoPath 2010 I did not get ExecuteAction under CurrentView